# Update page layout <head> based on angular prod mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli

## Scenario

I need to add an analytics script tag at the top of the `<head>` in the page layout. The script needs to be different depending on if we are in prod or development so we do not corrupt production analytics with QA testing.

I read that nowadays analytics tags don't necessarily need to be placed in the `<head>` anymore. Normally that would be fine, but in this project if there are any issues at all and the client found out we didn't follow the documentation we would get the blame for not implementing it correctly. Therefore, I cannot wait until client side angular has loaded to check the environment variable to make the switch using js, since that will be too late. I need this to be done during the build step before the browser loads the page.

## Temporary solution

The temporary solution I have is to create a second index.html (index-dev.html), and use a second app in the angular-cli.json file that uses this new file. This looks similar to

```
"apps": [
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "index": "index-prod.html"
   ...
},
{
  "name": "myApp-dev",
  "index": "index-dev.html"
   ...
}]
```

Then when I build for dev I would run

```
ng build --app=myApp-dev
```

and for prod

```
ng build --prod
```

I don't like this solution because

1. It adds two index files to maintain if I ever need to make a change
2. I now have two "apps" when I really only need one, more things to document and opportunity for mistakes down the road, etc.
3. If I am ramping up another developer and they run `ng build` in this scenario, they will be getting the production analytics script. I could switch the order of the apps in the array so dev is built by default, but now I'm in a situation where `ng build --prod` is building with the development analytics script.

## Main questions

1. Is there a way to tokenize the `<script>` element in the index file, and swap that out based on the environment?
2. If #1 is not possible, is there a way to let angular cli (or webpack, or some other tool) handle which index file is displayed using the --prod parameter? e.g. `ng build` would serve index-dev.html and `ng build --prod` would serve index-prod.html.